# Can a style be added to a System.Data.DataRow

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, datarow

I'm looping through each column and retrieving the row column value. Now based on some condition I want to add colour to that particular row. Is that can be possible

```
foreach (var columnName in ColumnNames)
{
 if(something) //true  , I want ot add colour and I tried

    dr[columnName] = "<span style='background-color:yellow;'>" + row[columnName] + "</span>";
}
```

But it is not displaying as text but not applying styles.How to add color to it

**Front End**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
<HeaderTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"/>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkItem" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkItem_CheckedChanged" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**CS**

```
foreach(GridViewRow gridRow in myGridview.Rows)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < myGridview.Columns.Count, i++)
    {
        if(gridRow.Cells[i].Text.Contains('*'))
        {
           //Do your thing 
           gridRow.Cells[i].Text=gridRow.Cells[i].Text.Replace(@"*", "");
           gridRow.Cells[i].Style.Font = 
            new Font("Ariel", 8, FontStyle.Underline);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `DataTable` is a C# in-memory object and not a UI component. Obviously you can't. Are you binding this DataTable to a databound control or something?

Comment: I'm binding it to a gridview

Comment: So apply the style in the gridview, if you want to do this based on some condition, do it in `RowDataBound` event.

Comment: Styling should be done at GridView not the DataTable object. Something like this : `<HeaderStyle BackColor="#eeeeee" />`

Comment: Actually I'm binding the datatable to gridview. Now I have to add columns instead of writing extra piece of code I wanted to know is anything simpler to do?

Comment: @DheerajPatnaik - Okay so you mean to say you have `AutoGenerateColumns` set to `True` ? Can you  a small sample data?

Comment: `gv.DataSource = GetData();gv.DataBind();`. GetData() is fetching data from excel and adding to datatable

Comment: @DheerajPatnaik - I mean in your aspx you have `AutoGenerateColumns="true" ` or there is nothing? You want to change color of row or column?

Comment: Just a column in a row and yes AutoGenerateColumns is set to true

Comment: @DheerajPatnaik - Check my answer and let me know if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `RowDataBound` event like this:-

Attach the event in your gridview:-

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gv_RowDataBound"></asp:GridView>
```

In Code behind:-

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (e.Row.Cells[2].Text == "Youvalue") //condition here
        {
             e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        }
     }
}
```

Here you need to specify the cell index accordinly which starts from `0`.

Comment: I have added my markup, for some reason it is showing only one column, the columns I'm binding from DataTable are not coming @Rahul Singh

Comment: @DheerajPatnaik - Showing one column means? Now gridview not binding?

Comment: I have added cs file, In my loop it is showing columns as count 1, i.e., of checkboxes

Comment: @DheerajPatnaik - Why you have added a `foreach` loop? where you are calling it? `RowDataBound` event anyways iterate for each row, you need to just specify the column number in `.Cells[2]` here that's it no loop required.

Comment: MIght be but I'm worried about the columns it is not showing all the columns

Comment: @DheerajPatnaik - Why you need count buddy? Simply do it the way I did, it will work as expected.

Comment: Thank u it did it for me @Rahul